# Form with Action element not triggering the email

Tags: html, forms, email, input, action

I have a form with action to third party URL it is not sending email when the action element is added to the form otherwise if we remove action="" its send the emails perfectly.

```
<form id="quote-forms" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">   
            <div style="display: none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1776486715" />
            <input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="awlist4465692" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.prioritymoving.com/quotes-form" id="redirect_740f29515aa8c7026603cd8e75a7bdb1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="Quote_Form_Priority_Moving" />
            <input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="custom mdate (awf_month)||preSelectedHeadingSelected,,custom mdate (awf_day)||preSelectedHeadingSelected,,custom mdate (awf_year)||preSelectedHeadingSelected,,custom dstate||Pick a state,,custom ostate||Pick a state" />
            </div>
           <label >Origin City</label>
             <input name="ocity" class="form-control-field" value="<?php echo $info[0] ; ?>"  placeholder="City" type="text">
             <label >Origin State</label>
             <input name="ostate" class="form-control-field" value="<?php echo $info[1] ; ?>"  placeholder="State" type="text">
              <input name="ozip" class="form-control-field" value="<?php echo $info[2] ; ?>"  placeholder="Zip Code" type="text">
             <input name="quote-forms"  value="Get Quote"   type="submit">
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

and this is how i am sending the email on the post of submit button: Can you please guide me how i can fix this that the action is there and it also send the email too..

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['quote-forms'])){

$oCity          = $_POST["ocity"];
$iZip           = $_POST["ozip"];
$oState         = $_POST["ostate"];

$to = 'shoaibswl123@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Quote Request From '. $fName ;

$message = '<html><body>'; 

$message = '<div style="background:#CEE4ED; padding:10px;>';
$message = '<div style="margin-left:30px;">';


$message .= "<b>Hi Admin,</b>";
$message .= 'You have received a new quote from the site with the following information';


$message .= "<b>Origin City: </b>" .$oCity;
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Origin Zip: </b>" . $iZip; 
$message .= "<br />";
$message .= "<b>Origin State: </b>" . $oState;
$message .= "<br />";

$message .= "<p>Thank you.</p>";

$message .= "</div></div>";

$message .= "</body></html>";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: '.$pEmail.'' . "\r\n";


 if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){

  echo "<div class='success-message'>Message Has Been Sent Successfully..!</div>";

  }else{

   echo "<div class='success-message'>There is an error while sending message..!</div>";
 }


  } ?>
```

Please help me on this...
Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the PHP part you're showing belongs to the same script than the HTML above. Right?

Comment: yes it is... @cFreed

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment in response to mine, all is clear:

- without à defined `action` the default one is the current page, so you recall your original script and execute the mail-related PHP part
- with `action` defined as you did, the cited script is called... and the original one is not!

What you should do is place your mail-related PHP part **inside of the `addlead.pl` script**.
Or, if not so easy (I don't even know what `.pl` refers to), you might:

- keep the mail-related PHP part in the original script
- keep the `<form>` without `action`
- in this part, just before the closing bracket of the whole block, add a redirection like `header('Location: ...the relevant url...');`

Comment: the action is going to AWEBER site to store all the filled information of subscriber there as we are using hidden fields to do so.. if will remove the action from the form it will no longer work and will not save the data to AWEBER. i have checked this. @cFreed

Comment: @Qasim _if will remove the action from the form it will no longer work_: wrong, it'll continue to work, thanks to the redirection added after sending the mail.

Comment: But if you see i have already defined the redirection in the hidden field at the top......
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.prioritymoving.com/thank-you/" id="redirect_740f29515aa8c7026603cd8e75a7bdb1" />

Comment: what you say about if i add my email code to thankyou page? when the page will be redirected after action it will trigger the mail function? but what will be if(......) condition check in that case

Comment: @Qasim With the code you shared, we don't know how and when the `redirect` data is used! So from your comment seems you have not only 2 different tasks but 3. Anyway, the solution remains the same, and you have merely to choose how and in which order you execute them. If you want more precisions, please show us the current code for the 3 tasks.

Comment: can i send you the file of my code so you can check it as whole?

Comment: Actuall the action goes to third party and and takes all the value with it and create a user there thats working fine but i also have to send all the information to an email to the site admin @cFreed

Comment: Is there not any other way to do so?

Comment: I have tried but the solution is not working for me... it goes to 404 page when click on submit button.. @cFreed

Comment: @Qasim _Actuall the action goes to third party_: does it mean that only sending mail is yours, and all the rest is achieved by `addlead.pl` (including doing something with the `thankyou` redirect)? If so, again, you can merely act like explained in my answer (the 3 last points).

Comment: @Qasim Regarding your comment about 404: if it's when using the 3-points solution, it comes from I too simplified. In `header('location: ...');`, replace `addlead.pl` by the relevant full url.

Comment: Yes i did this.. replaced with the full URL:

Comment: here is the link to my file that include whole code please check what wrong i am doing  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3dgBRofir8ZcjFURE9kbW9GTnc

Comment: @Qasim Checked all your code, nothing new here. So I keep surprised you get a 404. Then you should: 1) Try with "Location:" instead of "location" (that I'd unadvently written) 2) If same result, on 404 check you read the really right url in the browser response 3) Check you can access the url (instead of getting 404) when manually inputting it in the browser.

Comment: @Qasim Sorry, I think you misunderstood my "nothing new here": I meant I didn't find anything in the code that would change my diagnosis, so I keep recommending my initial solution. Now the point is: why this 404? It's why I proposed the 3 checks in my previous comment. So what about them?